# Iterating through string then checking an object

Tags: javascript

Obviously you iterate through a string quite simply:

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  console.log(str.charAt(i));
}
```

However, I'm looking to then check if the individual character is found in an object.

such as:

```
function("abc") {
   dictionary = {a:"1",b:"2",c:"3"};
// I'd then like it to output the argument all together.
// output would in this case would be "123"
}
```

I've done this before without the iteration for an argument, but can't make sense of how it's done with iteration. The specific string is an argument.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you have to clarify this a bit. So you check each character of your string against the keys of your dictionary object?

Comment: How would that dictionary look for a string like `abba`? I can't quite make sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up a character from the dictionary by using:

```
dictionary[character]
```

...and the rest is easy:

```js
var dictionary = {
  a: "1",
  b: "2",
  c: "3"
};

function mapChars(str) {
  var output = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    output += dictionary[str.charAt(i)];
  }
  return output
}

console.log(mapChars("abc"))
console.log(mapChars("aaabbbccc"))
console.log(mapChars("cabcbab"))
```

Or, if you can use ES6 syntax, then you can use a `for..of` loop:

```js
const dictionary = {
  a: "1",
  b: "2",
  c: "3"
};

function mapChars(str) {
  let output = ""
  for (const char of str)
    output += dictionary[char];
  return output
}

console.log(mapChars("abc"))
console.log(mapChars("aaabbbccc"))
console.log(mapChars("cabcbab"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) which accepts a string as the first argument since it's iterable, and provides a map callback as the second argument in which you can map each character to a key.

```js
const keyAccessFromString = (string) => {
  const dictionary = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" };
  return Array.from(string, c => dictionary[c]).join('');
}

console.log(keyAccessFromString('aec'));
console.log(keyAccessFromString('abc'));
```

Comment: I don't see the need for optional chaining here; `dictionary` is defined and not null so the optional part will never be used. I could see using the nullish coalescing operator `dictionary[c] ?? ""`...

Comment: lol, so true. spacing out. edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the string using the `map` method and check if `dictionary` contains that character:

```js
function alphabetIndex(str) {
  dictionary = {
    a: "1",
    b: "2",
    c: "3"
  };

  return str.split("").map(char => {
    if (dictionary[char]) {
      return dictionary[char]
    }
  }).join("")
}

console.log(alphabetIndex("abc"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach spreading the input string to array and using `reduce()`

```js
const keyAccessFromString = (str) => {
  const dict = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" };
  return [...str].reduce((a,c) => a + (dict[c] || ''),'') ;
}

console.log(keyAccessFromString('aec'));
console.log(keyAccessFromString('abc'));
```